# Proof environment produces "Proof Proof: ..." only when thmbox is used

Tags: amsthm, thmtools

I'm using `thmtools`. When I use the `thmbox` keyword in a theorem environment definition, all the proofs start with "Proof Proof: ".

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    thmbox=S,
]{thmsty}
\declaretheorem[style=thmsty]{thm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{thm}
        There are infinitely many prime numbers.
    \end{thm}
    \begin{proof}
        Exercise for the reader
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image: proof proof]

If I remove `thmbox=S` from the style definition, the problem is fixed:

[image: proof]

EDIT: I read in `thmbox` documentation that it redefines the `proof` environment. How can I prevent that? Adding `\usepackage{thmbox}` at the top solves the problem of "Proof" being written twice. However, the style still isn't like before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's a bug in `thmtools`, as far as I can see. However, the `proof` environment, as defined by `thmbox`, is not really what I'd like to use. You can reinstate the one by `amsthm` in the following way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\LetLtxMacro\amsproof\proof
\LetLtxMacro\amsendproof\endproof

\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \LetLtxMacro\proof\amsproof
  \LetLtxMacro\endproof\amsendproof
}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    thmbox=S,
]{thmsty}
\declaretheorem[style=thmsty]{thm}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
There are infinitely many prime numbers.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
Exercise for the reader
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! I had almost solved the problem by copying the definition of the proof environment from `amsclass.dtx`, and using `\renewenvironment`. However it still wasn't working properly as for some reason the "Proof" word wasn't italicized. This solution is better.

Comment: @egreg: Nice to see this. As a hack I used `\begin{proof}[\empty]`, which gives the desired output. But using the amsthm version of the proof environment is much nicer.

Answer (score 0):

This hack also works. Just type in preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\proof}{type whatever you want}
```

Example:

```
\renewcommand{\proof}{\textit{Proof.}}
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,thmbox=L]{thm}

\renewcommand{\proof}{\textit{Proof.}}


\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
There are infinitely many prime numbers.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
Exercise for the reader
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! I'm afraid this is not a good idea. This hack ignores whatever else the `proof` environment does. Indeed, it ignores the fact that it is an `environment` at all.